# How can I remove everything from a Commerce cart if a certain product is added, except that product?

Tags: commerce

I'm sure this is pretty simple to do but I'm spacing out on it.

If a product of a certain type is added to the cart, I want to remove everything in the cart , regardless of its type, except for that product. At the same time I need to make sure that the quantity for that product will never exceed 1.

I've started a [`hook_commerce_cart_product_add()`](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites!all!modules!commerce!modules!cart!commerce_cart.api.php/function/hook_commerce_cart_product_add/DC) implementation but I haven't got very far with it:

```
function MYMODULE_commerce_cart_product_add($order, $product, $quantity, $line_item) {
  if ($product->type == 'the_product_type') {
    // Now what?!
  }
}
```

I'm more than happy to use Rules instead of custom code for this, but again I haven't got very far trying it that way.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code I ended up using:

```
function MYMODULE_commerce_cart_product_add($order, $product, $quantity, $line_item) {
  if ($product->type == 'directory_subscription') {
    $order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);

    // Loop through the line items
    foreach ($order_wrapper->commerce_line_items as $delta => $line_item_wrapper) {
      // If this is the product we're keeping, make sure the quantity is always 1.
      if ($line_item_wrapper->commerce_product->product_id->value() == $product->product_id) {
        $line_item_wrapper->quantity->set(1);
        $line_item_wrapper->save();
      }
      else {
        // Remove any other product from the order
        commerce_cart_order_product_line_item_delete($order, $line_item_wrapper->line_item_id->value());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If anyone has any suggestions on how to improve the above I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 8 it should look like:

```
function remove_all_products_except_some()
{
  $orders = \Drupal::service('commerce_cart.cart_provider')->getCarts();
  $items = reset($orders)->getItems();

  foreach ($items as $item){
      foreach ($orders as $order){
        if (SOME CONDITION) {
           $order->removeItem($item);
         }
      }
    }
  }
}
```